# CodedUI, how to add additional controls into previous mapped hierarchy/page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests

How do I add additional controls to an already mapped UI? For example, I have a page that has buttonX, buttonY and buttonZ. Then I mapped it with the cross-hair tool and the following tree structure is generated when I used `Generate Code`

```
PageWindow
   SubPageWindow
      RadioButtonX
      RadioButtonY
      RadioButtonZ
```

How, say I added a Checkbox and an Edit UI to the same page. When I record the UI again, I would get two tress structures as such:

```
PageWindow
   SubPageWindow
      RadioButtonX
      RadioButtonY
      RadioButtonZ
PageWindow1
   SubPageWindow
      CheckBox
      BoxEdit
```

How do I make CodedUI to put CheckBox and BoxEdit to the old tree structure instead of making a new one? I have tried drag and drop after `Generate Code`, but that does not work. There is a Design.cs file which is auto-generated and it says

```
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
```

So I don't think I should modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the UIMap code isn't meant to be modified as it will get overwritten every time you build your solution.
Follow these steps to add extra controls to the UIMap:

1. drop crosshair on the control of your choice
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + I
3. Click the generate code button

If you want to add more controls in 1 session, repeat steps 1 and 2. Finish with step 3.
Controls can only be in the same tree if they have a mutual parent control. In your case the recorder sees your PageWindow1 as a other control than PageWindow. If you would like to have them on the same tree, you can try to add all those controls (RadioButtonX, RadioButtonY, RadioButtonZ, CheckBox and BoxEdit) in one session, thus repeating steps 1 and 2 five times. That should do the trick.

You can remove doubles in your UI Control Map tree view afterwards by selecting a control and pressing the delete button.

Comment: @cli2, if the answer is unclear to you, or did not answer your problem, please tell us so we can help you solve your problem. If the answer did solve your problem, you should mark it as the correct answer so other community members can see your problem is resolved.